# How does Ultra-pasteurized milk compare with pasteurized milk?

Tags: proteins, nutrition, milk

I am specifically interested in whether all proteins and nutrients lose their structure permanently because of the very high temperature of ultra-pasteurization. 
What is the case for pasteurized milk?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? What have you found?

Comment: From the basic web research I did, I found that many proteins are permanently destroyed. However, I would prefer someone with references to a study on this.